# Bootstrap multiselect select all checked by default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, default, selectall, bootstrap-multiselect

i use bootstrap-multiselect (v0.9.8) with option

```
 includeSelectAllOption: true
```

it is posible that select all to be checked by default when page is loaded?

thx.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following is taken from http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/, and I am currently using this solution with bootstrap 3.3.1 and bootstrap-multiselect v0.9.8
Be sure to add the false parameter to the 'selectAll' function as that permits you to select all the options without first opening the dropdown.

Example HTML:

```
<select class="multiselect" id="my-multi-select" name="options[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Example javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $('#my-multi-select').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });

    $("#my-multi-select").multiselect('selectAll', false);
    $("#my-multi-select").multiselect('updateButtonText');

});
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day by `$("#my-multi-select").multiselect('updateButtonText');`

Comment: This does not seem to work. The checkbox "Select all" remains unchecked.

Comment: Can you list what versions you are using and the code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap-select V.1.12.4, the solution is simpler:

Example HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="my-multi-select" name="options[]" multiple>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Example javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#my-multi-select').selectpicker({
    });
    $("#my-multi-select").selectpicker('selectAll');
});
```